# 3 point Newton Cotes Open Rule

Tags: python

I am new to python. Why the Convergence rate is all zero?

I'm trying to answer this question: Do a simple mesh refinement study to find the rate of convergence for the three point Newton-Cotes Open Rule.

My text function is sin(x)/x. i.e. integral from -1 to 1 of (sin(x))/(x).

```py
def f(x):
    return np.sin(x)/x

def Two_Pt_Gauss(f=f,a=-1,b=1,n=400):
    w1 = 1.0
    w2 = 1.0
    x1 = .57735227
    x2 = -.57735227
    Area = w1*f(x1) + w2*f(x2)
    return Area

## Convergence rate for Two Point Gauss
def Error(trueValue,Aziegbemi):
    return abs(trueValue-Aziegbemi)

def ConvergenceRate(ErrorVec):
    rateVec = []
    for i in range(len(ErrorVec)-1):
        rateVec.append(np.log(ErrorVec[i]/ErrorVec[i+1])/np.log(2.0))
    return rateVec

eps = 1e-16 
trueValue = 1.89217
AreaVec = []
ErrorVec = []
for i in range(7):
    n = 2**(i+1)
    AreaVec.append(Two_Pt_Gauss(f,0+eps,1.0,n))
    ErrorVec.append(Error(trueValue,AreaVec[i]))

RateVec = ConvergenceRate(ErrorVec)

print("Area = ", '%.9f' % AreaVec[1])
print("Area Vector: ",AreaVec)
print("Erro Vector: ", ErrorVec)
print("Convergence Rate: ", RateVec)
```

OUTPUT:

```
Area =  1.890725367
Area Vector:  [1.890725366594047, 1.890725366594047, 1.890725366594047, 
1.890725366594047, 1.890725366594047, 1.890725366594047, 
1.890725366594047]
Erro Vector:  [0.0014446334059527999, 0.0014446334059527999, 
0.0014446334059527999, 0.0014446334059527999, 0.0014446334059527999, 
0.0014446334059527999, 0.0014446334059527999]
Convergence Rate:  [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `Two_Pt_Gauss` doesn't use `n` at all, so it returns the same value every time. Then every element in `AreaVec` is the same, so every element in `ErrorVec` is the same, so every element in `RateVec` is `np.log(1)/np.log(2)`, which is 0. To fix this, you need to make `Two_Pt_Gauss` use `n` in some way.

Comment: Thank you. I will restructure the formula to be in terms of `n` and see how that goes shortly.